# Spring Boot doesn't read properties from Kubernetes Secrets

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

I have both `Secret` and `ConfigMap`. Everything is fine with `ConfigMap` but the issue is with `Secret`.

So first thing I did was adding the properties as environment variable:

```
      containers:
        - name: {{ include "helper.app-name" . }}
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: {{ include "helper.app-name" . }}-config
          - secretRef:
              name: {{ .Values.credentials.secretName }}
```

Properties named with dot such as `my.property.name` doesn't work even in ConfigMap which was surprising for me because a few years ago the same thing was working nicely. It only works if I change the name to `MY_PROPERTY_NAME` but this is not convenient because there can be 10 or 20 properties and converting them to that format is error prone.

So then I decided to add the properties as YAML file:

```
# configmaps
data:
  application-configmap.yaml: |-
     my.property.name: A Name
```

And mounted them as below:

```
spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: {{ include "helper.app-name" . }}-config
            items:
              - key: "bootstrap.yaml"
                path: "bootstrap.yaml"
              - key: "application-configmap.yaml"
                path: "application-configmap.yaml"
 ...
 containers:
     ....
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: "/config"
              readOnly: true
            - name: secret-volume
              mountPath: "/secret"
              readOnly: true
```

Now ConfigMap works but secret doesn't! Whether it's as environment variable or as a file, it just doesn't work. (Note: I have set active profiles to `configmap` already)

Then did some investigation and tried Spring Cloud:

```
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config:3.0.2")
```

With this in `bootstrap.yaml` defined in ConfigMap:

```
    spring:
      config.import: optional:configtree:/secret
      cloud:
        kubernetes:
          reload:
            enabled: true
          secrets:
            enabled: true
            name: my-secret-config
```

and the secret:

```
# secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret-config
stringData:
  my.credentials.password: somepass
```

But no luck. I added `spring.config.import` property after seeing it somewhere but it just doesn't like Secret.

Please note that I have added `Role` and `RoleBinding` with read permission from `configmaps` and `secrets` to the `ServiceAccount`.

One more thing is that when I mount the secret, like below, later on when I check the yaml output of the deployed POD, strangely it's not there. It's like K8s ignores it:

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secret-volume
              mountPath: "/secret"
              readOnly: true
```

I dug in everywhere including StackOverflow and Spring Cloud docs and tried everything but nothing is working.

Does anyone know what is missing here? I prefer not using Spring Cloud as it needs more dependencies unless that is the only way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After digging the internet I finally fixed this and I am answering my own question in case someone else has similar problem.

So first thing, I've included the following hard-coded property to my `ConfigMap` to let Spring know where the properties are:

```yaml
#configmap.yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
  SPRING_CONFIG_IMPORT: "file:/config/application-configmap.yaml,file:/secret/application-secret.yaml"
```

Then I mounted both my `ConfigMap` and `Secret` to match the above path:

```yaml
spec:
  container:
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: "/config"
      readOnly: true
    - name: secret-volume
      mountPath: "/secret"
      readOnly: true
```

And that fixed the problem. So the missing part was `SPRING_CONFIG_IMPORT` property that tells Spring where to look at for extra properties files.